# Reposition cursor in UISearchBar TextField with a label on top

Tags: ios, objective-c

- I have label view on my searchBar with title as "12345"
- This label is positioned to be on top of textField part of UISearchBar
- Now I am trying to position cursor after the label "12345"

I did this:

```
UITextField *searchBarTextField = [self.searchField valueForKey: @"_searchField"];

UITextRange *selRange = searchBarTextField.selectedTextRange;
UITextPosition *selStartPos = selRange.start;
NSInteger idx = [searchBarTextField offsetFromPosition:searchBarTextField.beginningOfDocument toPosition:selStartPos];

idx = idx + 150;
[Util selectTextForInput:searchBarTextField atRange:NSMakeRange(idx, 50)];
```

Util.m

```
+ (void)selectTextForInput:(UITextField *)input atRange:(NSRange)range {
    UITextPosition *start = [input positionFromPosition:[input beginningOfDocument]
                                                 offset:range.location];
    UITextPosition *end = [input positionFromPosition:start
                                               offset:range.length];
    [input setSelectedTextRange:[input textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end]];
}
```

But it does not reposition my cursor. What is missing?

Comment: Please close/delete this question...I will use UITextView instead

Answer (score 1):

Create the label inside the tableView`s delegate Method add the label to the UISearch bar .

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //get the content of selected cell 
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // now you can get the any content of the selected cell , for example 

    //Create your label
    UILabel *label = [UILabel alloc] init];
    label.text = selectedCell.label.text;
    /...customize your label as you wish .../

    //lastly add the label to the UISearch
    [yourSearchBar addSubView: label];


}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I should have asked that I want to position my cursor after the label. I found the solution. I will probably delete this question.